# Failed to install an auto prefixer extension for brackets

Tags: brackets

I have created my web page, and I need to simplify a manual work for prefixes by installing autoprefixer in my bracket code editor. I have tried to install it in two ways, one by pressing installation button found from search, and by copying github link.

below is a screenshot. Please anyone who can help me to solve this problem. Thanks[image: r]

Answer (score 0):

What I did is to close my editor and restart in again, then everything work fine